# Fetching error on my chrome console I tried using different browses as well but still not solved

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

### **Fetching error on my chrome console I tried using different browsers as well but still not solved**

```
fetch('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd')
.then(res => {
    console.log("Response Awaits to Parse");
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("Data Parsed");
    console.log(data.ticker.price);
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log("Error NO!!!", e);
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYjU6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmBuf.png)

Comment: You are missing the parsing part. You should have a `return res.json()` or something in the first `.then()`. You should also check `res.ok` to see if the request was actually successful (it was not).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 503 Error, which means the server is not ready to handle the request. Basically it means the problem is on the server side, not on you app. Check here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503?retiredLocale=uk